# Java- starting thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading

Here's part of my simple code.This code contains moveable oval and static oval with coords `newX=100,newY=100`.I'm trying to achieve moving that movable oval automatically after hitting left mouse button.Move code lines are in new Thread `thread`.Thrad really starts with clicking mouse button, but nothing happens.Just after doing one move using arrow keys, oval starts moving.I tried calling `repaint()` method at different places but it doesn't seem to help.Any suggestions? Thank you!

```
public class Buffer extends JPanel implements Runnable,KeyListener,MouseListener{
public static int x;
public static int y;
public static int newX;
public static int newY;
public static Thread thread;
public static boolean check;
public static JFrame frame;
public static int pointX;
public static int pointY;
public static boolean repaint;


public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawOval(x, y, 20, 20);

        newX=100;
        newY=100;
        g.fillOval(newX, newY, 20, 20);

        if(repaint)
            repaint();
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Buffer z=new Buffer();
    z.setBackground(Color.white);

    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.addKeyListener(z);
    frame.addMouseListener(z);
    frame.add(z);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();

    thread=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                    x=x+i;
                    repaint=true;
                    thread.sleep(1000);

                }
            }catch(InterruptedException v){System.out.println(v);}
           }
        };

}
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        x=x-10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
        x=x+10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP){
        y=y-10;
        repaint();
    }
    if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_DOWN){
        y=y+10;
        repaint();
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying shared variables from a thread, and reading them from another, without any kind of synchronization. That's wrong. Every access to a shared variable must be done in a synchronized way, or thread-safe objects (like AtomicInteger for example) should be used.

Moreover, the thread modifies the `x` value in a loop, but never calls `repaint()`, so there's no reason for the panel to repaint itself.

Comment: I cannot call repaint() in static method.That's why I used boolean variable repaint to trigger repaint() method in paintComponent method.

Comment: changing a boolean value won't magically call a method. You need to call repaint() on the buffer. So, call `z.repaint()` (and make the variable `z` final to be able to do that from an inner class). That said, all these variables and methods should *not* be static. I have the feeling that you don't understand the basics of OO yet. Learn the basics first before using Swing, and even more, threads. Concurrent programming is *extremely* complex.

Comment: I tried it and now it works.I've just expected changing boolean variable would call repaint from block `if(check) repaint();`.Anyway thank you very much.Your feeling is not far from reality.I'm pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that is the possible issue here but I am going to give it a try:

Try using AtomicInteger for the `x` and `y` variables as the code is not thread-safe.

You are trying to access shared variable across multiple threads and doing increment operation which is not atomic and thus is not thread safe.

```
private static AtomicInteger x = new AtomicInteger(0); //take the initial value that you need

//where you are incrementing the x
x.incrementAndGet();


//where you want to read x
value = x.get();
```